# what is the different between onCreate() and onCreateView() lifecycle methods in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, oncreate

I don't know when to use `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

I have used `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` lifecycle methods. 
I think `onCreate()` for Activity and `onCreateView()` for Fragment. But I am not sure. Can I use `onCreate()` LifeCycle method in Fragment? I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: check the android developer docs and maybe you will find a solution

Comment: have you read fragments [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?

Comment: Google - https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=oncreate+vs+oncreateview

Answer (score 85):

**onCreate** is called on initial creation of the fragment. You do your non graphical initializations here. It finishes even before the layout is inflated and the fragment is visible.

**onCreateView** is called to inflate the layout of the fragment i.e graphical initialization usually takes place here. It is always called some time after the **onCreate** method.

Answer (score 8):

Activity lifecycle explained - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Fragment lifecycle explained - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Detailed lifecycle diagram - https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Comment: Simple links don't answer questions. For instance, in the lifecycle there's no mention of the createView.

Answer (score 0):

### From documents :

> **onCreate**
>
> Called when the activity is starting.
>
> This is where most initialization should go: calling setContentView(int) to inflate the activity's UI, using findViewById(int) to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI, calling managedQuery(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[], String) to retrieve cursors for data being displayed, etc.
>
> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest of the activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

[Link to documentation of `onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

> **onCreateView**
>
> Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view. This is optional, and non-graphical fragments can return null (which is the default implementation). This will be called between onCreate(Bundle) and onActivityCreated(Bundle).
>
> If you return a View from here, you will later be called in onDestroyView() when the view is being released.

[Link to documentation of `onCreateView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: This doesn't answering the question as the `onCreate()` described is for Activity. The reason is simply because question is asking about Fragment. Not to mention, Fragment does not have `setContentView()` method.