# Difference and uses of onCreate(), onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, oncreate, fragment-lifecycle

What are the differences between `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, and `onActivityCreated()` in fragments and what would they each be used for?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227906/where-is-the-diferent-between-oncreate-and-oncreateview

Comment: @BradLarson I don't understand why this had been closed. It has proved to be a relatively popular question and is different to the link stated in your comment. This question is asking for the difference between the three different methods and how they compare to each other but the question you linked in your comment only mentions two of these methods.

Comment: @BradLarson Fair enough and well spotted. Now though that I have an understanding, could I not write an answer which better compares the three methods, referencing the links for additional details?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh - Sure. I've reopened the question, if you think you can provide a better answer. I just didn't want to leave it sitting unanswered if I could.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

[`onActivityCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) is deprecated from API Level 28.

---

**onCreate():**

The `onCreate()` method in a `Fragment` is **called after the `Activity`'s `onAttachFragment()`** but before that `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`.
In this method, you can assign variables, get `Intent` extras, and **anything else that doesn't involve the View hierarchy** (i.e. non-graphical initialisations). This is because this method can be called when the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` is not finished, and so trying to access the View hierarchy here may result in a crash.

**onCreateView():**

After the `onCreate()` is called (in the `Fragment`), the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` is called. You can assign your `View` variables and **do any graphical initialisations**. You are expected to return a `View` from this method, and this is the main UI view, but if your `Fragment` does not use any layouts or graphics, you can return `null` (happens by default if you don't override).

**onActivityCreated():**

As the name states, this is **called after the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` has completed**. It is called after `onCreateView()`, and is mainly used for final initialisations (for example, modifying UI elements). This is **deprecated** from API level 28.

---

**To sum up...**
... they are all called in the `Fragment` but are called at different times.
The `onCreate()` is called first, for doing any non-graphical initialisations. Next, you can assign and declare any `View` variables you want to use in `onCreateView()`. Afterwards, use `onActivityCreated()` to do any final initialisations you want to do once everything has completed.

---

If you want to view the official Android documentation, it can be found here:

- [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))
- [`onCreateView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater%2C+android.view.ViewGroup%2C+android.os.Bundle))
- [`onActivityCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))_

*There are also some slightly different, but less developed questions/answers here on Stack Overflow:*

- [`onCreate()` vs `onCreateView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227906/where-is-the-diferent-between-oncreate-and-oncreateview)
- [`onCreateView()` vs `onActivityCreated()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041206/android-fragment-oncreateview-vs-onactivitycreated)

Comment: I thought I would implement non graphical initialisations at onCreate() so that they would not be called again when the screen is rotated. It turns out that I have to call fragment.setRetainInstance(true) otherwise both onCreate() and onCreateView() are called again when the screen is rotated.

Comment: In onCreateView(),  is that safe to access view hierarchy ?

Comment: @Cody I believe so - accessing the view hierarchy is the exact purpose of `onCreateView`.

Comment: However, activity's onCreate() might not finished until onActivityCreated() ?

Is these any chance of crash in onCreateView for accessing view hierarchy ?

I am not sure what's difference between onCreateView() / on onActivityCreated()

Comment: @Cody Read my answer in more detail; `onCreate` is called first, then `onCreateView`, then `onActivityCreated`. There should be no crashes if you are correctly accessing the view hierarchy in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` - it doesn't matter which, but usually, graphical initialisations are done in `onCreateView`.

Comment: One thing to note (at least with the AppCompatActivity) is that when the activity is recreated (e.g. after being minimised and killed) the fragments onCreate() will be called before the the activities onCreate() and  super.onCreate() are finished. This can be a problem if you are using something like Dagger and need to access something in the parent activity that is injected. One solution to this is to put the code in onActivityCreated() which is called always called of onCreate() is called.

Comment: If i need to get some data from DB, process it and create graph (or maybe adapters). should i do that in onCreate (just process data from db), onCreateView , onActivityCreated or onStart ?

Comment: @razor I don't think it makes a huge difference, `onCreate` is probably best but it depends on when you want the processing to be done. Just keep in mind that you can't access the view hierarchy in `onCreate`.

Comment: Is it save to assume that the activity's `onCreate` has finished, once the `onCreateView` of it's Fragments is called?

Comment: There is pretty much no need to use `onActivityCreated`, ever, and just use `onViewCreated` instead.

Answer (score 171):

For anyone looking for a concise, pictorial answer:

[image]
*https://hanaskuliah.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/android-5-development-part-6-fragment/*

---

And,

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Comic Sans is necessary for things like this

Comment: It's the first time I see 3 different fonts in the same diagram, and somehow my life feels complete now.

Comment: When exactly could a fragment restart?

Comment: How come the fragment is not re-created once it's process is dead? AFAIK, only the task state preserved as a bundle and it's re-created the app is brought to foreground again.

Answer (score 13):

### onActivityCreated() - Deprecated

`onActivityCreated()` is now deprecated as Fragments [Version 1.3.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02)

> The onActivityCreated() method is now deprecated. Code touching the
>   fragment's view should be done in onViewCreated() (which is called
>   immediately before onActivityCreated()) and other initialization code
>   should be in onCreate(). To receive a callback specifically when the
>   activity's onCreate() is complete, a LifeCycleObserver should be
>   registered on the activity's Lifecycle in onAttach(), and removed once
>   the onCreate() callback is received.

Detailed information can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144309266)