# unfortunately mainactivity has stopped is showing due to copy and paste

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator, android-xml

I have developed a program which is working in android studio.
Three components of this program are MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml and list_item.xml as following

Comment: where is your logcat??

Comment: Provide the error you are receiving in the Logcat when the application terminates.

Comment: the logcat is bellow the android studio

Comment: Please post UserProfile.java too

Comment: Post the layout `activity_user_profile`

Comment: `textView3` is not inside `activity_user_profile` or its children. Where is this textview?

Comment: textView3 is  inside the first_layout.xml

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi: Looks like a copy paste error and you are using wrong layout in `UserProfile`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should move

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

textView.setText("Welcome "+username);
```

to onCreateView instead of onCreate in UserProfile.java

You can look at the answer here : [Difference and uses of onCreate(), onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
```

should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.user_activity_profile);
```

in `UserProfile` `onCreate` method because the xml you have posted is `user_activity_profile.xml`

Comment: I have posted the logcat.

Comment: the problem is in `UserProfile` class. Check if you have used correct layout in that and all the id's you are using in that class is inside that layout.

Comment: You need to post code of `UserProfile.java` and the layout used inside it. You can remove rest of the posted code except the logcat.