# appropriate place signOut() method google api

Tags: android

After peeking at [firebase goolge api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect) i had a curiosity, in what place of the lifecycle in an applicaiton invoking the google api within the fragments would it be appropriate to call signOut()? i'm currently reviwing [this super amazing lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra) and noticed that onStop() for a fragment has an 'app process kill' state. it's because of this that i chose to put the signOut listener in the onCreate, am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found it's best to use an interface for signingOut().

```
public interface SettingsIf{
 void logOut();
}

public class A implements SettingsIf{
 void someFunction(){
  logOut();
 }
}
```