# Fragment Recyclerview onCreateView, onViewCreated or onActivityCreated?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment-oncreateview

Should i initialize my recyclerview in onCreateView, onViewCreated or onActivityCreated?

What's the difference between those 3, i searched for explanations but some people say to use onCreateView and some say to use onViewCreated or onActivityCreated And only to use onCreateView to inflate layout?

**This is my code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    recyclerViewSongs = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSongs);

    initRecyclerView();

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView called!");

    return rootView;

}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    Main.musicList = Main.songs.songs;

    // Connects the song list to an adapter
    // (Creates several Layouts from the song list)
    allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(getContext(), Main.musicList);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerViewSongs.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewSongs.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewSongs.setAdapter(allSongsAdapter);

    recyclerViewSongs.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(getContext(), new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (! Main.songs.isInitialized())
                    return;
                //Start playing the selected song.
                playAudio(position);
            }
        }));

}
```

Comment: read this , its explain everything https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateView()` will be the best choice since you're using `Fragment`. The difference is `onCreateView()` is the `Fragment` equivalent of `onCreate()` for Activities and runs during the `View` creation but `onViewCreated()` runs after the `View` has been created.

And `onActivityCreated()` calls after `onCreate()` method of the `Activity` completes as you can see in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582434/4409113

Answer (score 1):

The best level to set RecyclerView is in onCreateView() which is equivalent to onCreate() in case of Activity because RecyclerView needs to be quick so as not to make the UI sluggish. Hence, RecyclerView in onViewCreated() will make the UI sluggish before populating UI.