# setOnClickListener in Fragment with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a sample code and I want a Button showing a message but it didn't work. App will open but buttonn didn't work

This app should show a Toast but it does not. I tried `lateinit var firstComend : Button` but didn't work too

I should sat will converting `Activity` to `Fragment`

Please help me

```
package com.mysfk.android.frogments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.mysfk.android.R
import android.graphics.Color
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast


private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"



class OrderFragment : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val let = arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

     var firstComend = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.firstButton)
        firstComend?.setOnClickListener {
  
            Toast.makeText(context, "ارسال شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
    
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            MessageFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fragment Recyclerview onCreateView, onViewCreated or onActivityCreated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522649/fragment-recyclerview-oncreateview-onviewcreated-or-onactivitycreated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your click listener inside the onCreateView, like this:

```
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
        var firstComend = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.firstButton)
        firstComend?.setOnClickListener {
  
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()`, so your button is always `null` when trying to set the `ClickListener`. https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states

Comment: so i should put on `CreateView()` before `onCreate()` ?

Comment: @AliDamiri check my edit answer please

Answer (score 0):

All view related decision must be done in onCreateView or onViewCreated

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
    }


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        var firstComend = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.firstButton)
        firstComend?.setOnClickListener {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```