# Is onActivityCreated() called after onViewCreated() in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have two ViewModels. One is used from the Fragment only and the other one is a shared ViewModel from the Activity.

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FragmentViewModel.class);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    activityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ActivityViewModel.class);
}
```

But in order to know if I can use the **content** from the activity's ViewModel, I need to know if the `onActivityCreated(...)` is called after `onViewCreated(...)` so I can request my data in the Fragment ViewModel based on data I have in the Activity's ViewModel.

To summarise:

**Is it for certain that `onActivityCreated(...)` is called after `onViewCreated(...)` has finished?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some further research I think I found the answer.

> **onActivityCreated** added in version 22.1.0 void onActivityCreated
> (Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this
> fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final
> initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving
> views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use
> setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, as this callback
> tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity
> instance. This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
> Bundle) and before onViewStateRestored(Bundle).

Based on the documentation:

> ..fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final
> initialization once these pieces are in place..

The view hierarchy should be fully instantiated and therefore `onActivityCreated` will be called after the completion of `onViewCreated`

**UPDATE**

Info: `onActivityCreated` is now deprecated

> use onViewCreated(View, Bundle) for code touching the Fragment's view
> and onCreate(Bundle) for other initialization. To get a callback
> specifically when a Fragment activity's Activity.onCreate(Bundle) is
> called, register a androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver on the
> Activity's Lifecycle in onAttach(Context), removing it when it
> receives the Lifecycle.State.CREATED callback.

Comment: Not related to this post but please be aware onActivityCreated is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @hemanthkumar, updated the text so it's clear

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is for certain, as you found out. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582434/2333010) for a cute little lifecycle drawing (the second one).

Comment: Please note that it is NOT onViewCreate but onViewCreated

Comment: I was actually convinced that `onViewCreated` was referenced to in the lifecycle :) anyway, your answer pretty much covers it.

Comment: @Javatar I edited my answer, you might want to check out the link.

Comment: Thats actually a really awesome lifecycle description. Thx

Comment: Glad to help :D