# Initialization Method for 'RecyclerView' crashes app when used with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-bottom-nav-view

I used a recyclerView on my app to display all files from an external storage. Until I changed it, it worked fine when it was implemented in the "MainActivity.java".

Now, I want my app to have a "BottomNavigationBar"; in order to do that, I use fragments. The problem is the app crashes when I touch the specific item from the menu (the one containing the RecyclerView).

I changed all the "this" method to ".getActivity()" but it crashed anyways. I changed it to ".getActivity().getApplicationContext()" but it still crashed.

I'm sorry, my computer does not support hardware acceleration so I can't properly show what the error is. Instead, I have attached a debugger to my connected phone and set up breakpoints. The debugger highlighted the line `"RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);"` when the app crashed.

Here's the fragment code:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_records, container, false);
    }

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> NbFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> PathFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Check if we have the permission to read storage
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //We don't have the permission, so request it.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
        //We already have permission
        else {
            permissionExists();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                permissionExists();
            } else {
                //handle error
            }
        }
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (RecyclerViewAdapter.OnNoteListener) this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    }

    private void permissionExists() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Rapture";
        File directory = new File(path);
        boolean success = true;
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            success = directory.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File[] arrayFiles = directory.listFiles();
            for (File file : arrayFiles) {
                mNames.add(file.getName());
                PathFiles.add(file.getPath());
                NbFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        initRecyclerView();
    }
}
```

[Let me know if you need more code]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: When `getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)` called in `onCreate(...)` it's cause NPE in `Fragment`. Use `onViewCreated(...)` instead

Comment: @Ricochet see my answer below..it will be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move below code for handling permission `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //We don't have the permission, so request it.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
        //We already have permission
        else {
            permissionExists();
        }
    }
```

In Fragment, you can initialize your view in `onViewCreated`

```
    // This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
    // Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Setup any handles to view objects here
         initRecyclerView(view);
    }
```

Change your `initRecyclerView()` like below,

```
private void initRecyclerView(View v) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (RecyclerViewAdapter.OnNoteListener) this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    }
```

It will shows `fragment` page without blank,

[image: Screenshot1]

For more clarification about life cycle of `Fragment`, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra)

Comment: This method works but now the fragment shows nothing. All the code concerning permission was moved to ```OnAtivityCreated```, ```PermissionExists``` does not call ```initRecyclerView``` anymore but ```onViewCreated``` does with the new ```initRecyclerView``` you provided...

Comment: Is it working now? Move your permission function in `onCreateView` or else do in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: The application does not crash anymore when I touch the concern item. But, the RecyclerView does not show any view. It did back when ```initRecyclerView``` was defined in the main java script. I am facing a blank page right now. (What do you mean by "Permission function" ?)

Comment: It worked. I realized I forgot to inflate the layout. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Happy to help you @Ricochet

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a misclick I was trying to reach the accept answer button. Since, I'm a new user, I can't change it back to normal... Again, I'm sorry this was not intended. Your answer is great.

Comment: @Ricochet No issues, thanks for your comment. I tried to improve my answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

Instead of `getView()`, you need to use the view inflated in `onCreateView`

So,

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_records, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        return v;
    }
```

If you want, you can then populate the RecyclerView (or make it visible, or whatever) in `initRecyclerView()`

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`getActivity()`  instance of `getView()`

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

instance of

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this-

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_records, container, false);
    initRecyclerView(view);
    return view;
}



private void initRecyclerView(View view) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (RecyclerViewAdapter.OnNoteListener) this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the onCreate mewthod and move the logic into onCreateView

Answer (score -1):

Here the issue is your `recyclerView` initializes by calling `getActivity()` but the problem is that the activity does not exist until `onActivityCreated()` is called.

So it's crashing. Move all of that code inside `onCreate()` to `onActivityCreated()` and it should work fine.